# Magnitude of Cross Product given 2 vector magnitudes and angle between them?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

if the magnitude of vector U is 6 and the magnitude of vector V is 9, and the angle between these vectors is 60 degrees, what is ||U x V||? Why is the answer not 54Sin(60)?[image]

Comment: What makes you think that it isn’t?

Comment: as noted by David pay attention with the angle when you calculate the value, $\sin60°$ should be equal to $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **really** meant $54\sin(60)$, then it is wrong because it should be $54\sin(60^{\rm o})$.  Check whether your calculator is set to degrees or radians.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct since

$$|\vec u \times \vec v|=|\vec u||\vec v|\sin \theta$$

Note also that this value correspond to the area of the parallelogram spanned by the two vectors and thus the area of the triangle with sides $|\vec v|$ and $|\vec u|$ is given by

$$A=\frac12|\vec u||\vec v|\sin \theta$$